# Unable to create a DIY Fusion Drive using a 3 TB hard drive

Tags: hard-drive, mac-mini, fusion-drive

I'm trying to make a Fusion Drive with a Samsung 830 256GB SSD and a 3 TB 3.5" HDD (connected via SATA to my late 2012 Mac mini). I'm able to create the Fusion Drive, but when I start to install Mountain Lion, it fails because it's unable to create a recovery partition. I have tried Fusion with a 640 GB or 1 TB hard drive, everything is working fine. Only the 3 TB (either Seagate or Western Digital) doesn't work: it can't create the Recovery partition.

Why could this be?

Comment: What were the instructions you followed to create the fusion drive, and what errors are you seeing?